# Need to identify component

Tags: pcb, identification, components

[image]I need to identify this component labeled TX08039 1119 on a pool pilot dig-220 power board 12042R2 in order to replace and repair chlorine generator for my pool, please. Pics of replacement board

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to replace it? Do you think it is broken? How did you determine it is broken? It looks like  a custom transformer for a switch mode power supply. Usually these don't get damaged unless you physically manage to break it. Likely the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: A mouse chewed wires off (along with part of component- dead mouse)going from component into  printed board

Comment: That is a pic of a new component

Comment: It's still a custom component you likely can't buy as there is no specification what kind of transformer it needs to be. Unless you have the service manual with part listing that shows it's a standard part with specific part number that is still orderable.

Comment: Looks like a weird common mode choke. Photo of bottom side?

Comment: It’s still attached to board

Comment: Looking at all the smoke deposits, that part drew a lot of current when the mouse shorted it. Good chance some semiconductors or other parts were damaged too. Bummer, but I'd say bite the bullet and buy a new board. And set mouse traps.

Comment: Smoke is from me trying to use butane torch to melt solder. I know to much heat

Comment: That's a transformer. These are almost always custom-wound for the application; replacing it will require either finding a service manual with information, or reverse engineering the circuit. It's likely your butane torch attempt ruined any possibility of directly measuring inductances.